# Getting assignees for a set of tasks

Tags: ruby, asana

I'm developing a tool to assign a bunch of tasks to a guy according to some criteria.
I fetch tasks for a given tag.
I only assign a task to a guy if the task has no assignee.

My problem comes with the last statement. Fetching a list of tasks do not provide enough information. Going through the documentation, I remember I can format the response with the fields I need using [`opt_fields`](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/#Options) but I don't succeed to implement it.

I have this piece of code:

```
# set up HTTPS connection
uri = URI.parse("https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tags/8232053093879/tasks?opt_fields=name,assignee")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

# set up the request
header = { "Content-Type" => "application/json" }
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path, header)
request.basic_auth(AppConfig[:api_key], '')

# issue the request
response = http.start { |h| h.request(request) }

# output
body = JSON.parse(response.body)
```

And it keeps responding with:

```
{"id"=>8232053093904, "name"=>"Implement open VPN"}
{"id"=>8232053093899, "name"=>"Implement a @emi tool for random task affectation."}
{"id"=>8232053093893, "name"=>"List possibilities for internal server hosting ?"}
{"id"=>8232053093890, "name"=>"Create a server FAQ (how to access, how to restart an app, how to set up a new server)"}
{"id"=>8232053093883, "name"=>"Help alban debug munin configuration (server monitoring tool)"}
{"id"=>8232053093876, "name"=>"Think how to improve nanoc deployment"}
```

While, using curl:

```
curl -u 8NYknPS.aMxj55LsWwwujpZgNqQ078xf: "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tags/8232053093879/tasks?opt_fields=name,assignee"
```

I get:

```
{"data":[
  {"id":8232053093904,"name":"Implement open VPN","assignee":null},
  {"id":8232053093899,"name":"Implement a @emi tool for random task affectation.","assignee":null},
  {"id":8232053093893,"name":"List possibilities for internal server hosting ?","assignee":{"id":1069528343983}},
  {"id":8232053093890,"name":"Create a server FAQ (how to access, how to restart an app, how to set up a new server)","assignee":null},
  {"id":8232053093883,"name":"Help alban debug munin configuration (server monitoring tool)","assignee":{"id":1069528343983}},
  {"id":8232053093876,"name":"Think how to improve nanoc deployment","assignee":{"id":753180655981}}
]}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to give the nested fields, like `?opt_fields=name,assignee,assignee.id` - it's a bit clunky, unfortunately. But if you just want the *whole* assignee, you can use `?opt_expand=assignee`.

Hope that helps!